# How do I create a graph in r which takes into account multiple values for one factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Context**

I'm trying to use R to analyze data for my bachelors thesis on wolves/Canis lupus.

I want to estimate wolf density from my data, using the REM (Random Encounter Model). I've managed to adapt the `remBoot` package for most of my data and it seems to work fine. However, I am suspicious that my Confidence Intervals (95%) seem to be very small.

**Main problem**

I am trying to create a graph similar to the one attached from Marcon et al. 2020  (see below)

Similar graph:

[image: Similar graph of Data]

Similar table:

[image: Similar table of data]

This is to account for the fact that there is different data on how far wolves travel per day (v), which is a main factor in the Random Encounter Model. Depending on the value v is calculated for, the density estimate (and the SD and the CI) should vary quite substantially.

I would like to create a graph that shows the change and trend of the density when the daily movement changes from v=9.4km to v=27.4km (values reported in the literature) incl. the change in 95% Confidence Intervals. Basically similar to the one attached.

I have tried quite a few things, but really can't find a solution.

I've trimmed down my code attempt to what I think is relevant for the question at hand. You will see that one calculation is always just the normal density, and **one is taking into account that a wolf pack has a group size of 2. That is the actual density I need to work with for the SD, CI etc.!**

Data:

```
> dput(rem1)
structure(list(site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), encounters = c(1L, 3L, 
0L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
14L, 0L, 1L), dist_km = c(0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 
0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416, 0.0221416
), tetha_rad = c(0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 
0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243, 0.7531243
), sd = c(0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 0.017419880337682, 
0.017419880337682), sd2 = c(0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289, 
0.0350864356194289, 0.0350864356194289), ci = c(0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 
0.0715322625737278, 0.0717674076098163, 0.0715322625737278), 
    ci2 = c(0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 0.142573149649466, 0.14396009276619, 
    0.142573149649466), se = c(0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935), se2 = c(0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 
    0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935, 0.00241150479395935
    )), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
##create function to calc dens according to group size (2)
remmi <- function(dat, tm, v){
  # Calculate y: total captures
  y <- sum(dat[,2])
  # Calculate the first half of the equation above
  trm1 <- y/tm
  trm2 <- pi/((v*mean(dat[,3], 
                      na.rm = TRUE)) * (2 + (mean(dat[,4], 
                                                  na.rm = TRUE))))
  # Calculate D GROUP SIZE 2
  return((trm1 * trm2)*2)
}

##alter remBoot to remBooty in order account for group size 2
remBooty <- function(.df, tm, v, nboots, error_stat){
  ## Written by Kevin Keenan 2013 and Anthony Caravaggi 2016
  ## distributed under GPL3
  bsD <- function(dat, tm, v){
    bsDat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE), ]
    dOut <- remmi(bsDat, tm, v)
    return(dOut)
  }
  grpDat_func <- function(df, x){
    return(df[which(df[,1] == x), ])
  }
  
  split_dat <- function(.df) {
    lapply(unique(.df[[1]]), grpDat_func, df = .df)
  }
  remmi <- function(dat, tm, v){
    # Calculate y: total captures
    y <- sum(dat[,2])
    # Calculate the first half of the equation above
    trm1 <- y/tm
    trm2 <- pi/((v*mean(dat[,3], 
                        na.rm = TRUE)) * (2 + (mean(dat[,4], 
                                                    na.rm = TRUE))))
    # Calculate D
    return((trm1 * trm2)*2)
  }
  grpDat <- split_dat(.df)
  remsD <- lapply(grpDat, function(x){
    d <- replicate(nboots, bsD(x, tm, v)) 
    return(d)
  })
  res <- list()
  if(is.element("sd", error_stat)){
    resSD <- lapply(remsD, sd)
    names(resSD) <- levels(.df[[1]])
    res$sd <- c(res, resSD)
  }
  if(is.element("se", error_stat)){
    resSE <- mapply("/",lapply(remsD, sd),lapply(grpDat, function(x) sqrt(nrow(x))),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    names(resSE) <- levels(.df[[1]])
    res$se <- c(res, resSE)
  }
  if(is.element("ci", error_stat)){ #quantiles replaced with CI function
    require(Rmisc)
    resCI <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(remsD, CI, ci = 0.95)))
    resCI$mean <- NULL
    rownames(resCI) <- levels(.df[[1]])
    res$ci <- resCI
  }
  if(is.element("quant", error_stat)){
    resCI <- t(sapply(remsD, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)))
    colnames(resCI) <- c("Lower", "Upper")
    rownames(resCI) <- levels(.df[[1]])
    res$ci <- resCI
  }
  return(res)
}

##define days and km and do first density calc
tm <- 3245
v <- 23.0666
##dens Group size 2
den2 <- remmi(rem1, tm, v) 
den2
##define number of bootstrap iterations for sd 
nboots <- 10000
remsD <- lapply(grpDat, boot_sd)
remsD
remsSD <- lapply(remsD, sd)
remsSD

##define parameters for remBoot
tm <- 3245
v <- 23.0666
nboots <- 10000

##GROUP SIZE 2 for SD using remBooty
outputsd2 <- remBooty(rem1, tm, v, nboots, error_stat = c("sd"))
outputsd2

##change class of SD into numeric for graph
rem1$sd2 = as.numeric(outputsd2$sd)

##GROUP SIZE 2 - remBooty - calc CI and change class to numeric
outputci2 <- remBooty(rem1, tm, v, nboots, error_stat = c("ci"))
outputci2

##change class of CI into numeric for graph
rem1$ci2 = as.numeric(outputci2$ci)

##GROUP SIZE 2 plot of dens with sd
ggplot(rem1, aes(x = site, y = den2)) +  
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="light blue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=den2-sd2, ymax=den2+sd2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Survey site") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Animals.km2") +
  ggtitle("Animal density estimates calculated with REM and remBoot")

##GROUP SIZE 2 plot for ci
ggplot(rem1, aes(x = site, y = den2)) +  
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="light blue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=outputci2[["ci"]][["lower"]], ymax=outputci2[["ci"]][["upper"]])) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Survey site") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Animals.km2") +
  ggtitle("CI2Animal density estimates calculated with REM and remBoot")
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here that isn't germane to your question.  It's good to narrow down your post to exactly what is needed to capture your question.  That way, it's easier to help you.  It's also easier for others to learn from your question if they find your post in the future.  Please see [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've reduced the code to what I think is relevant. I hope that helps. Thanks, Christan

Comment: That's better - there are still a few elements of your post that make it difficult to work with.  You'll get better help, faster, if you use the [mcve] approach.  I often find I'll actually solve my own problem sometimes when I'm trying to refine the way I'm asking a question.  Just my $0.02.  In your case, there are at least two issues:

Comment: (1) You are asking more than one question.  And the first one, about checking CIs, is not appropriate for this site (it's also not very specific).  (2) All of the specifics about wolves is hard to follow, and not really about coding - it's problem solving for your general task.  For your specific question about plotting with `ggplot`, just give a `dput()` of `rem1`, and explain how the plot you have is different than the plot you want.

Comment: Dear Andrew, all in all I'm happy with my results – so far. I tried to give some background info because I thought it might help in understanding. In future I'll try to focus on the coding part. The graph I get so far for the density (den2) including the 95% CI works fine for one single fixed v (km) value. I would like a plot that shows the difference in density when factor v=9,4 increases all the way to v=27,4 incl. the changing CIs. Similar to the Graph I included the picture of from Marcon et al. Do you see what I'm looking for?  Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Regarding question (1)  – I'm just suspicious about the small CIs I'm getting, but can't find where I could be wrong so I hope my approach is correct. However you are probably right, that might not be a question for this site.

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece, so the question was edited and specified again. Is there any advice you could give? Thanks and best regards, Christan

Comment: It's a lot better - but still too much code, imo. Notice how 66 people have viewed this post already, and no one has attempted an answer? That's usually a sign that you haven't distilled your question enough for others to easily help. I may have time next weekend to help, can't now. But really, have a look at [ask] and then see if you can condense your post to just the call to ggplot and the data needed to generate a [mcve].  As it is, it's visually difficult to sift through the noise of your problem space to get to the signal of your specific question. Up to you of course, just my $0.02.